# In Oracle SQL -> How to convert a Hex-number to a Signed 32-bit integer (ie not to a decimal number)

Tags: oracle

In Oracle SQL I can convert a hex-number = b60d9800
into a decimal-number = 3054344192
by using the query:

`select to_number('b60d9800', 'xxxxxxxx') from dual`

but I also need it to give me the signed-32-bit-integer = -1240623104

Does anyone know how to do this conversion using Oracle SQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate 32-bit signed integer overflow in PL/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847674/how-to-simulate-32-bit-signed-integer-overflow-in-pl-sql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle hex to number conversion dword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306017/oracle-hex-to-number-conversion-dword)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at [How to simulate 32-bit signed integer overflow in PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847674/how-to-simulate-32-bit-signed-integer-overflow-in-pl-sql)
which doesn't fully solve my question (but lead me in the right direction) I came up with the following solution:

```
select (case when m> 2147483647 then (m - Power(2,32))
                                else (m) end) a
from (select mod(n, Power(2,32)) m 
      from (select to_number('b60d9800', 'xxxxxxxx') n from dual))
```

Comment: You can also replace 2147483647 with ((Power(2,32) / 2) - 1) to get: select (case when m > ((Power(2,32) / 2) - 1) then (m - Power(2,32)) else (m) end) a from (select mod(n, Power(2,32)) m from (select to_number('bcc9c000', 'xxxxxxxx') n from dual))
;

Comment: You can also replace it with  `m >= power(2,31)`

Comment: Thanks - so it becomes -> select (case when (m >= Power(2,32) / 2) then (m - Power(2,32)) else (m) end) a from (select mod(n, Power(2,32)) m from (select to_number('bcc9c000', 'xxxxxxxx') n from dual))

Comment: You can edit your answer (look for "edit" button under the post). Also, `power(2,31)` is easier to understand, IMHO.